# java to firebase real time database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question.

We received data from sensors through Arduino.

Then Arduino sent the data to Java.

And I want to send that data from Java to "Firebase realtime database."

To read data from Firebase, it was printed by switching to json string.

I want to know how to link the database to 'Firebase realtime database' from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has a Admin SDK for Java, which you can use in trusted environments. If your setup is a trusted environment, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

If it isn't a trusted environment, there is no Java SDK from Firebase. In that case the best solution would be to access the Realtime Database through its REST API, which is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Answer (score 0):

java script ok ?

```
// Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

Comment: Is it only possible with a Java script?

Is it impossible with the Java project?